# htaccess, append a forward slash, then remove and process without altering the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite all urls from say, `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/`

I have a rule that adds the forward slash:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]`

I would like to create another rule. It's purpose is to check if a trailing slash is present. If so, it then removes it for processing without altering the URL shown in the browser.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules for that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L]
```